# Configuring Grails 3 for Log4j2

Tags: grails, slf4j, logback, log4j2, grails-3.1

We would like to use Log4j2 as the log binding with grails 3.

From what I can figure out so far.  We have many subordinate dependencies that use a variety of loggers, so we need to use the SLF4J API.  Then, instead of letting grails / groovy / spring re-direct the SLF4J API to the Logback binding, we need to re-direct each to the Log4j2 binding.

Since grails 3 uses the Logback binding, I am planning to go through each dependency in the build.gradle, exclude the Logback binding, and include the Log4j2 binding.  Will this work?   Update: Yes

Do we also need to bridge the Log4j2 API to the SLF4j API?  What dependency do we need for that?  Update:  See below.

Finally, I assume we need to ditch the grails 3 logback.groovy configuration and just put one of the log4j2 configs in src/main/resources.  Update: Yes

I'll post updates as we figure this out, but I bet someone has done this before.

Update 2016-03-18:

This turned out to be very straight-forward.  I did a './gradlew dependencies' on my grails 3 project to see which dependencies were pulling in the Logback binding/implementation (group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic')

First, here's the default build.gradle generated via a 'grails create-app testit' command:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.2"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "testit"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.4"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

The dependency report showed that they were being pulled in by two dependencies:

```
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
```

and

```
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
```

So, I only had to make a couple changes to the dependencies section of the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // commented out the original way using Logback    
    //compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"

    // added the new way using Log4j2, yes, spring makes it easy
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"

    // changed spring-boot-autoconfigure so that it would not
    // pull in the logback binding/implementation
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure') {
       exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    }

    // and finally, added the log4j2 binding/implementation
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5"
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5"

    // the rest is unchanged
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.4"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

In the src/main/resources, we added a log4j2.xml.

In the groovy code, we used:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(getClass())

log.info('Hello World')
```

We also put ThreadContext statements in the constructors of heavily used classes.

That was it.  Now we're doing fast, async logging that doesn't lose any log messages upon config changes.

Comment: Thank you for this. If you had added an answer I would have voted for it. This was exactly what I needed to make Grails 3.1.10 to usse log4j2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forgot to post something as an answer.  Here's an answer you can vote for, but I put all the information about the solution in the comments above.

Comment: I would highly suggest updating your Q&A to separate them into the correct format.. meaning question goes where the question goes only, and your answer here I am commenting on includes your answer..