# log4j with Grails 3.2.3: I don't get any logging

Tags: spring, logging, grails, log4j

I am not able to get log4j to work in a project with Grails 3.2.3.
My aim is to get detailed logs of the spring security plugin, because I have some problems with it and want to know whats going on (I cannot login although I provide correct credentials).

I added the following lines to `grails-app/conf/application.groovy`:

```
log4j = {
    all 'org.springframework'
        'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core'
    debug 'grails.app'

    appenders {
        file name: 'file', file:'logs/logging.log'
    }

    root {
        all 'stdout', 'file'
    }
}
```

But when I run the application with `grails run-app` or `run-app` in the interactive mode, no file is created, and there is no output in the console, even if I try to log in and the login fails (which should of course create some log messages, especially because of the log level "all").

I am no expert with `log4j`. I never used it before.
I read through some tutorials and documentation, but they are all related to plain java programmes, not Grails.

Most of my Grails configuration is in YAML (`application.yml`), only the spring and `log4j` settings are in a separate `application.groovy`. As far as I understand, Grails merges them into one Configuration Object.

What do I miss in my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default `logback` is used in Grails 3.x for logging. In order to activate it, you must have a `logback.groovy` in your `grails-app/conf`. Usually it looks like:

```
import grails.util.BuildSettings
import grails.util.Environment
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender

// See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html for details on configuration
appender( 'STDOUT', ConsoleAppender ) {
  encoder( PatternLayoutEncoder ){ pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %level %logger{36} - %msg%n' }
}

root INFO, ['STDOUT']

logger 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme', DEBUG

def targetDir = BuildSettings.TARGET_DIR
if( Environment.developmentMode && targetDir ){
  appender( 'FULL_STACKTRACE', FileAppender ){
    file = "${targetDir}/stacktrace.log"
    append = true
    encoder( PatternLayoutEncoder ){ pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %level %logger{36} - %msg%n' }
  }
  logger 'StackTrace', ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false
}
```

Here the Spring Sec's rememberme services are logged to stdout with DEBUG level

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason I missed this information in the Grails doc. Now the log is created. Still some fine tuning to do, but it works thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the version of `Log4j`, however, I guess it was `Log4j2` as you said Grails 3.2.3. Therefore, my recommendation below is based on `Log4j2` [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). According to Log4j2 manual, you must have a configuration file in the project classpath. The classpath can be `src/main/groovy/resources` or `grails-app/conf`. The configuration file can be a `{xml|json|yaml}` as guided in the manual.

Below is a very simple content of the configuration file that is working for my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
                     filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz"
                     filePermissions="rw-------">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy stopCustomActionsOnError="true">
                <PosixViewAttribute basePath="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}" filePermissions="r--r--r--">
                    <IfFileName glob="*.gz" />
                </PosixViewAttribute>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Also, there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074899/configuring-grails-3-for-log4j2) on this community I reckon you might need just in case. The question tried to detail how to configure `log4j2` in Grails 3.

I hope this explanation would help clear your issue.